# How can I convert BSON (Binary JSON) to human readable data using Clojure?

Tags: clojure, bson

I was wondering if anybody has a solution or knows of any resources that would allow me to convert BSON into human readable data for use with MapReduce using Cascalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [clj-bson (available at clojars)](https://clojars.org/clj-bson), you can decode bson into clojure map and do with it anything you want.